# Meta skeptics.SE HTTPS seem to be misconfigured

Tags: bug, status-deferred

This is what I'm getting over https right now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266711/1438). We do have a plan to fix it, but it's going to be the [proverbial 6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/1438).