# Yellow https warning in FireFox when going to a question

Tags: bug, status-deferred

This is what the Firefox<sup>*</sup> address bar shows on the main page if I visit the site over https:

[image]

This is what it shows for every question I visit:

[image]

The associated messages are something like (my translation):
*Connection is not secure. This website does not offer identity information. Parts of the website are not secure.*

Is something misconfigured?
It's not [this issue](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/meta-skeptics-se-https-seem-to-be-misconfigured) reported last February (that was about meta sites being inaccessible over https).

<sup>* Latest version 48.0.2 under Win7 64</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: yeah, apologies, we know, we are working on it, it will take time.

Long version. This is as expected. While we are trying to move to https first, at the moment we only support http. The reason is a bit complex.

Our URL naming structure for meta sites sucks for https, as every meta site at the moment would need a specially crafted certificate. This is hugely expensive in terms of ongoing maintenance. Main sites are fine because we have a cert for `*.stackexchange.com` which we can reuse. Before the end of the year we want to migrate all metas from `meta.<site>.stackexchange.com` to `<site>.meta.stackexchange.com`, this allows us to purchase a `*.meta.stackexchange.com` certificate and cover all of them.

The problem is that we need to migrate *all references to the old metas first* to the new metas (and to https). And this is a bunch of work, think of posts, comments, help pages... etc.

Furthermore, we need to migrate all the linked resources to https: images, avatars. Again -- a lot of work, which is also dependent on whether we can guarantee a http version or not. Gravatar needs to support it, imgur needs to support it, etc. etc.

Comment: Ah, so it *was* the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you switch to Let's Encrypt for TLS certificates? As long as you're not hitting their rate limit, you could easily set up automated scripts to obtain certificates for all the domains.